# java.lang.SecurityException: my location requires permission ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION

Tags: android, typescript, gps, location, nativescript

I have a question about my code.

So, I'm using nativescript-geolocation for get my location.

In component.ts I have this code:

```
import * as geoLocation from "nativescript-geolocation";
 currentGeoLocation: any;

       ngOnInit(): void {
            geoLocation.isEnabled().then(enabled => {
                if (!enabled) {
                    geoLocation.enableLocationRequest().then(() => geoLocation.watchLocation(location => {
                        this.currentGeoLocation = location;
                        this.mapView.longitude = this.currentGeoLocation.longitude;
                        this.mapView.latitude = this.currentGeoLocation.latitude;
                        this.mapView.zoom = 15;
                        console.log(this.currentGeoLocation)
                    }, error => {
                        alert(error);
                    }, {
                            desiredAccuracy: 3,
                            updateDistance: 10,
                            minimumUpdateTime: 1000 * 1
                        }));
                } else {
                    geoLocation.watchLocation(location => {
                        this.currentGeoLocation = location;
                        this.mapView.longitude = this.currentGeoLocation.longitude;
                        this.mapView.latitude = this.currentGeoLocation.latitude;
                        this.mapView.zoom = 15;
                        console.log(this.currentGeoLocation)
                    }, error => {
                        alert(error);
                    }, {
                            desiredAccuracy: 3,
                            updateDistance: 10,
                            minimumUpdateTime: 1000 * 1
                        });
                }
            });
        }
```

In AndroidMainfest.xml I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

When install application show [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkukX.png)

Comment: have you given permission at runtime

Comment: I don' understand?In witch file?

Comment: wherever you are doing location related tasks, you need to check for permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Android architecture**

**As per Android doc:**

> Android 6.0 Marshmallow introduced a new permissions model that lets
>   apps request permissions from the user at runtime, rather than prior
>   to installation. Apps that support the new model request permissions
>   when the app actually requires the services or data protected by the
>   services. While this doesn't (necessarily) change overall app
>   behavior, it does create a few changes relevant to the way sensitive
>   user data is handled:

If the user is running Android 6.0 (API level 23) or later, the user has to grant your app its permissions while they are running the app. 
So you need to add run-time permission.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as Permissions from "nativescript-permissions";

declare var android: any;

@Component({
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {

    public getCameraPermission() {
        Permissions.requestPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA, "Needed for connectivity status").then(() => {
            console.log("Permission granted!");
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log("Permission is not granted (sadface)");
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: In witch file I put run -time?

Comment: If you are usign native script then follow this link:thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2017/08/request-android-permissions-nativescript-angular/

Answer (score 0):

in Android M, you need to request run-time permission

Answer (score 0):

- Here Some simple steps to get Permission on Runtime from the user.

**1)** add below implementation in build.gradle file.

> **implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'**

**2)** Add below code to get permission at what you want location from user.

```
Dexter.withActivity(activity)
                .withPermissions(
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport report) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onPermissionsChecked: ");
                        // check if all permissions are granted
                        if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
                            // All permissions are granted!

                            // Do what you want to do.

                        } else {
                            // Some permissions are not granted!
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> permissions, PermissionToken token) {
                        token.continuePermissionRequest();
                    }
                }).
                withErrorListener(new PermissionRequestErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onError(DexterError error) {
                    }
                })
                .onSameThread()
                .check();
```

- **Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION** and **Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION** both use to get Location.
- **Function** :-

  ```
  if (report.areAllPermissionsGranted()) {
         // Write code to get Location.
  }
  ```

**This function is to check permission granted by the user or not. If yes then it goes in.. And after that write your Code to get Location from User.**